# Best way to log app data from a console app running inside a container on ACI

Tags: azure, logging, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

A seeming simple ask, but had no luck finding the best way.

So i need to log application events from a console app that will spin up inside a container and do some work then die.

How can i log custom data from inside?

I've tried Azure Monitor and created a workspace and used HTTP Data Collector API inside the app but no joy in working out where logs are being stored.

Is there a simple way to log to an Azure Storage account and then using Azure Monitor to manage the events?

I've been googling for hours but a lot of posts are 8 years old and not relevant and i cannot really find a simple use case in modern azure.

Perhaps it's so simple i just cannot see it

Any pointers or links greatly received!

thanks
Paul

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-insights-overview

Comment: +1 on AppInsights. You just need to use the AppInsights SDK and provide the Instrumentation Key for your AppInsights instance as an env variable when starting the ACI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not trace events using Application Insight custom events ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics

With that you can trace events with any metadata and check them in the Azure Application Insights Blade or reach them by the Application Insights SDK or The Api.

You just need to create an Application Insight instance and use the Telemetry Key to do that.

SDK: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet

API : https://dev.applicationinsights.io/reference

Code sample to write events:

```
  TelemetryClient client = new TelemetryClient();
  client .InstrumentationKey = "INSERT YOUR KEY";
  client.TrackEvent("SomethingInterestingHappened");
```

Also you can send more than just an string value:

```
tc.TrackEvent("PurchaseOrderSubmitted", 
  new Dictionary<string, string>() 
  { 
    {"CouponCode", "JULY2015" } 
  }, new Dictionary<string, double>() 
  { 
    {"OrderTotal", 68.99 }, 
    {"ItemsOrdered", 5} 
  });
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks. That seems like a good approach so i added the sdk, set up a new Insight in azure added the key - it all runs - but i get no data (or errors from the client). I even added the client.Flush() in case things aren't being written. I am literally firing up a hello world console application and added an event before and after the hello world part.

Reading the docs it is very skewed towards asp.net applications. So i am wondering in the context of a console app (which will be running in a container) whether this approach will work?

thx
Paul

Comment: @paulinventome can you share the code for your example? Note that event when calling `Flush` it may need some time to send the data so if the container is killed right after the hello world it might have not made it. Also, it can take up to a minute or so before data is displayed in the portal. And yes, containerized console apps are supported, we have them running and reporting to AI as well.

Comment: Exactly because under the hood it is prepared for massive event streaming so it works like a kind of batch operations if you are killing the container right after execute it probably you won't see the result, please share your code to check if there is something missing.

Comment: The code is dead simple and i suspect it's being killed for it gets a chance to send anything. This is what i thought flush was - to explicitly transmit the event data?

`TelemetryClient client = new TelemetryClient();
            client.InstrumentationKey = "xxx";
            client.TrackEvent("fR Console Start");


            Console.WriteLine("Hello fr World!");

            client.TrackEvent("fR Console Finish");

            client.Flush();`

Comment: How long should i idle the container afterwards?

Comment: Okay, that was it. I added a Thread.Sleep at the end of the console run and now i can see some custom events. Thanks all...

Comment: your welcome @paulinventome and great thanks you too Peter